# iOS keyboard sound bug (once loud then normal)

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

There is a seldom loud "tap" sound, when I type inside `UITextField` in my app. Problem appears when I type some number of characters (it's not necessary to do it fast) - all "taps" play at the same sound level, one - louder. And it looks like there is some micro-delay / hang up before loud sound.

I tried to put new `UITextField` on the screen (to test without display settings and additional behavior - with only `frame` and `autoresizingMask` changed). Still happens.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Got bug on device. Tested on iPhone 5, iPhone 6, iPad 3. Sound is not so loud on iPad, but yet slightly louder.

Comment: Is it on device or in simulator?

Comment: @Kreiri device (updated question).

Comment: Have you tried turning off keyboard click sounds in Settings?

Comment: @Kreiri, but I don't want to remove it. Just to avoid this strange bug (I don't see it in other apps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very strange case...

In my app I'm trying to detect muted sound (by switch or volume = 0). The only way to do it is to play sound with silence (sound file with no real sound) and measure it (when sound is muted, play time will be small [empirics here] - only to launch operation).

So to make this check automatic, I've created background task with infinite loop for observation. And this is the way the bug appeared: lag is not on each tap, but if you quickly tap a lot of times, you will 100% get it.